# Generar una imagen a partir de una cuadro de datos y asignar color de acuerdo a una tercer columna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pillow

Tengo un cuadro de datos:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"TRACK_ID": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
    "X": [10, 75, 50, 300, 400, 12, 17, 27, 30, 45, 40, 15, 65, 400, 19, 45, 234],
    "Y": [10, 75, 50, 300, 500, 10, 105, 200, 100, 305, 420, 17, 47, 176, 20, 165, 375],
    "distance": [92, 35, 354, 224, 0, 95, 95, 100, 205, 115, 0, 58, 359, 0, 147, 282, 0]})
```

que produce el siguiente DataFrame en pandas

`Out[56]: 
    TRACK_ID    X    Y  distance
0          1   10   10        92
1          1   75   75        35
2          1   50   50       354
3          1  300  300       224
4          1  400  500         0
5          2   12   10        95
6          2   17  105        95
7          2   27  200       100
8          2   30  100       205
9          2   45  305       115
10         2   40  420         0
11         3   15   17        58
12         3   65   47       359
13         3  400  176         0
14         4   19   20       147
15         4   45  165       282
16         4  234  375         0`

El ejemplo representa 4 trayectorias distintas identificadas por su TRACK_ID y las columnas `X` y `Y` representan las coordenadas de cada trayectoria. Adicionalmente la ultima columna representa la distancia lineal entre cada punto `X-Y`

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es generar una imagen con cada trayectoria, en donde el valor de la columna `distance` en cada fila, determine el color de la linea a dibujar.

Actualmente mi codigo puede generar una imagen, pero cada trayectoria tiene su propio color:

```
df = data.set_index(['TRACK_ID'])
M = [1,2,3,4]
df1 = df.loc[M,:]

tracks = df1.groupby('TRACK_ID')
img = Image.new("RGB", (512,512), "black") 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

for e, group in tracks:
    coords1 = tuple(zip(group.X, group.Y))
    draw.line(coords1, width=3) 
img.show()
```

Esto genera una imagen como la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora estoy atorado en como generar un diccionario con una paleta de colores de acuerdo a la magnitud de la columna 'distance'
Cualquier aportación se agradecería mucho
Saludos

Comment: El color solo dependería de distance o sería también diferente para cada trayectoria (un mapa de color para cada una)? ¿Que intervalos de distancia y color para cada uno querrias usar?

Comment: La idea es graficar todas las trayectorias en una misma imagen, el mapa sería el mismo para todas las trayectorias. Los intervalos serían arbitrarios, yo estoy pensando en usar de 8 a 6 colores, pero no estoy seguro si se puede usar asignar un LUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder asignar un color distinto a cada segmento se hace en principio necesario llamr a line por cada par de puntos contiguos de cada trayectoria, pasando el color correspondiente mediante el aargumento fill.

Generar el mapa de color es otra historia, una forma muy básica sería usar una lista de colores predefinida y repartiendo cada uno en intervalos de igual longitud comprendidos entre el valor mínimo y máximo de la columna de distancias:

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


def colormap(colors, lim_inf, lim_sup):
    inter_dif = (lim_sup - lim_inf) / len(colors)
    inters = (lim_inf + inter_dif * r for r in range(1, len(colors) + 1))
    hcmap = list(zip(inters, colors))
    def cmap(value):
        for lim, color in hcmap:
            if value <= lim:
                print(color, value)
                return color
    return cmap 


data = pd.DataFrame({
    "TRACK_ID": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
    "X": [10, 75, 50, 300, 400, 12, 17, 27, 30, 45, 40, 15, 65, 400, 19, 45, 234],
    "Y": [10, 75, 50, 300, 500, 10, 105, 200, 100, 305, 420, 17, 47, 176, 20, 165, 375],
    "distance": [92, 35, 354, 224, 0, 95, 95, 100, 205, 115, 0, 58, 359, 0, 147, 282, 0]}
    )


df = data.set_index(['TRACK_ID'])
M = [1, 2, 3, 4]
df1 = df.loc[M,:]

tracks = df1.groupby('TRACK_ID')
img = Image.new("RGB", (512, 512), "black") 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

colors = ["LightCoral", "Salmon", "DarkSalmon", "LightSalmon",
          "Crimson", "Red", "FireBrick", "DarkRed"]
cmap = colormap(colors, data["distance"].min(), data["distance"].max())

for e, group in tracks:
    it = group.itertuples()
    _, lx, ly, ld = next(it)
    for _, x, y, d in it:
        draw.line(((lx, ly), (x, y)), width=3, fill=cmap(ld))
        lx, ly, ld = x, y, d
img.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Recomiendo emplear la librería matplotlib. Es mucho más flexible para dibujar trayectorias, eligir colores, tipos de línea, etc.. También esta muy bien integrado con pandas. Es fácil para cambiar la resolución y el tipo de las imágenes guardados. La función [`plt.savefig`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) puede aceptar todo los parámetros de `PIL.save` (y muchos más), o se podría [convertir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8598881/12046409) a una array para emplear directamente con PIL.

La primera ventaja es que las líneas tienen *antialiasing* (quitando el efecto escalera). También se podría añadir un colorbar para muestrar que color corresponde con que valor.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({"TRACK_ID": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
                     "X": [10, 75, 50, 300, 400, 12, 17, 27, 30, 45, 40, 15, 65, 400, 19, 45, 234],
                     "Y": [10, 75, 50, 300, 500, 10, 105, 200, 100, 305, 420, 17, 47, 176, 20, 165, 375],
                     "distance": [92, 35, 354, 224, 0, 95, 95, 100, 205, 115, 0, 58, 359, 0, 147, 282, 0]})

df = data.set_index(['TRACK_ID'])
M = [1, 2, 3, 4]
df1 = df.loc[M, :]

tracks = df1.groupby('TRACK_ID')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('off')
fig.set_facecolor('black')
norm = plt.Normalize(df1.distance.min(), df1.distance.max())
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm')
for e, group in tracks:
    for k in range(len(group) - 1):
        dist = group.iloc[k].distance
        ax.plot(group.iloc[k:k + 2].X, group.iloc[k:k + 2].Y, color=cmap(norm(dist)), lw=3)

cbar = plt.colorbar(plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm))
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(color='gold', labelcolor='gold')
cbar.set_label('distancia', color='gold', fontsize=14)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('mis_tracks.png', facecolor='black')
plt.show()
```

[image: resultado]

Comment: No es exactamente lo que busco, estoy tratando de que cada segmento que compone las trayectorias tenga un color de acuerdo a intervalos arbitrarios de desplazamiento, información que viene dada por la ultima columna

Comment: ¿Se puede hacer con matplotlib? PIL viene de tiempos antiguos.

Comment: Claro que se puede, quizá este mal, pero personalmente  no uso matplotlib porque la imagen que genero la sigo editando en imageJ y con matplotlib el gráfico no es una imagen donde se puede modificar la profunidad de pixel y el formato de salida?